# Trouble on handling cookie data with time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, timezone

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to handle data present in cookies the proper way. That is, when I store to cookie data as-like `(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)`

```
cookies.permanent[:time_zone] = "(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

then in the cookie content it is stored `%28GMT-06%3A00%29+Central+Time+%28US+%26+Canada%29`.

That way, when I use the `cookies[:time_zone]` data in my code

```
Time.use_zone(cookies[:time_zone], &block)
```

then I get `ArgumentError Invalid Timezone: (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)`.

I think the problem is due to the fact that the `cookies[:time_zone]` data is read from cookies "as it is" (`%28GMT-06%3A00%29+Central+Time+%28US+%26+Canada%29`), so it generates the error when called in `Time.use_zone`.

How should I read / write the cookie data?

---

**UPDATE after @Matt Johnson comment**

My "hadcode" is

`time_zone = cookies[:time_zone] || Time.zone`

so that I can use the `time_zone` variable for my matters. However, I noted that `Time.zone` returns always

```
(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
# instead of "Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

*It is the problem*: in my "hardcode" when the cookie is `nil` then `Time.zone` should return the proper value for my matters, that is `Central Time (US & Canada)`.

*So my question become*: how should I handle the issue in order to properly set the `time_zone` variable?

*Notes*: The [`Time.zone` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone) states that the method

> Returns the TimeZone for the current request, if this has been set
>   (via ::zone=). If Time.zone has not been set for the current request,
>   returns the TimeZone specified in config.time_zone.

and in my `application.rb` file I have set

```
`config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`
```

Comment: Where are you reading that value to begin with?

Comment: I am reading it from the default Ruby on Rails settings.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Please show *the code* that you are using to read the time zone setting string.

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean with "show *the code* that you are using to read the time zone setting string".

Comment: In your question, you are showing a hardcoded string of `"(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)"`.  Is that hard coded in your application? Or are you retrieving it somehow?  It should just say `"Central Time (US & Canada)"`.  The `"(GMT-06:00) "` is not part of the identifier.

Comment: @Matt Johnson - I updated the question. I do not know if it can help to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, note that by assuming the issue was about cookies, you fell into the trap that is known as the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails time zones are listed [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html). In this particular case, you should drop the first part of your string and just pass `"Central Time (US & Canada)"`.

You may also want to read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), which has a section about Rails time zones toward the bottom.

**Updated Answer**

Based on your update, I can see that you are using `Time.zone`.  This doesn't return a string, but returns a `TimeZone` object.  So you are getting the effect of [`TimeZone.to_s()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-to_s) which includes the GMT portion.

You should instead use `Time.zone.name`, which just returns the string identifier of the time zone.

Comment: I read the "timezone tag wiki", even the "Rails Time Zone Identifiers" section specific to Ruby on Rails... so, how I should read / write the cookie data in my case?

Comment: The problem isn't with the cookie at all.  It's that the string you are passing to `Time.use_zone` is not a valid time zone identifier.  That's what the message says "Invalid Timezone".

Comment: What I have to store in cookies instead of `(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)`? Where I can retrieve the proper data to store?

Comment: Thanks. *BTW*: Is there a method as-like `Time.default_zone` (that returns the same as `Time.zone.name`)? ... I am using a similar "hardcode" even for internationalization and there is the `I18n.default_locale` method.

Comment: I see `Time.zone_default` in the docs, but haven't tried it.  That might have what you're looking for.

Comment: I run `Time.zone_default` and I get *NoMethodError (undefined method `default_zone' for Time:Class)*. However, for now, your solution works. :-)